# Zapier Twilio integration is very slow. Is there a way to filter with Zapier and send SMS with Twilio with no delay?

Tags: twilio, zapier

I have created a Zap to send an SMS to a mobile number every time a new email, with a specific subject, is received.

I've created two tasks:

1st. Zapier Filter, filters the emails by the right subject.
2nd. Twilio send this email as SMS.

I find that it takes up to 10 minutes or more for that email to be sent as an SMS, and time is very relevant in this automation. Is there a way to speed up the process so Twilio sends the SMS as soon as the email arrives and Zapier has filtered it?

I am not 100% sure where us this delay happening. Zapier or Twilio?

Thanks,

Aitor

Answer (score 1):

There is a Twilio You Tube Tutorial which shows you how to set-up email to SMS, this could be another way to set-up the same requirement.

[How to forward email to text messages using Twilio and SendGrid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxd4jm0YwoY)

To identify your current issue, you can send the email, record the time, and then check the Twilio Console messaging logs to find the SMS message associted with that email and record the time; then compare the time differences.

Answer (score 1):

*This delay is only happening because of the plan you have on zapier.*

If you upgrade your plan, their event listeners can run <1 minute, but on the lower tier plans, you can except 5-10 minute delays.  Check out their pricing page & look at the update time:

[Zapier pricing](https://zapier.com/app/billing/plans)

If you want this to run faster & don't want to upgrade zapier plans, the option above is a great choice.